# Topology on modules

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

Take $M$ an $R$-module with $R$ a commutative ring with unit. Let's take on $M$ a linear topology in the following way.

Take $M=M_0 \supset  ... \supset M_n \supset M_{n+1} \supset ...$ a chain of $R$-submodules and take the topology on the group $(M,+)$ such that it's a topological group with fundamental system of neighborhoods of the neutral element is given by $M_n$.

The questions are:

> If take $R$ with the discrete topology then $M$ is a topological module?

> From the precedent points, I can say that for any topology on $R$ we have $M$ topological group?

> If $M$ is a ring with a linear topology given like above, is $M$ a topological ring.

Comment: You cannot ensure that $M$ is a topological module without specifying a topology on $R$ first. The discrete one on $R$ will only very rarely have a chance of working (if $M$ is discrete e.g.).

Comment: Thanks, I was reading here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_topology can you help me to understand it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this linear topology. I only know a bit about topological groups and TVS's. Hopefully others can provide more insight.

Comment: Read Bourbaki? See the reference on Wikipedia... It's wiser to use books than random stubs on Wikipedia to learn maths IMO.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean with $M$ discrete?

Comment: I should say that $R$ discrete work because for any $r,x \in R\times X$ the counterimage of $rx+M_n$ contain $r\times x+M_n$ which is an open and so the coutnerimage is a neighborhood.

Comment: For $M$ to be a topological group, it needs to be Hausdorff, which in context means you need to assume $\bigcap M_n = 0$